# Ethereum Solidity Examples

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain

I am pretty now the blockchain/solidity/ethereum world. I started in February, reading and diving into the world. Currently, I am trying to implement a simple game with ethereum and the help of smart contracts. I am using solidity because vyper is too new and there is more stuff to read and learn from solidity.

While researching the web for different questions about my problems and my observation in solidity/smart contract i never could find good resources or github repos that show how the actual work was don. (or it was in solidity 0.4.5, which is pretty old now).

I am using Truffle with Ganache to test out my application.

So i though i could get help from someone here in this community. Can someone recommend me their go-to websites or whatever, when trying to learn and understand smart contract and solidity.

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

- [General](https://ethereum.org/developers/)
- [On-Chain](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/)
- [Off-chain](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/)
- [Testing](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs)

Comment: i meant like a website, where i can see solidity source code for different projects done. Like we can find them in java, python etc.

Comment: @Luka96: GitHub or Etherscan.

Answer (score 1):

For Python and server-side interaction

- [web3.py](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/)
- [Brownie](https://github.com/iamdefinitelyahuman/brownie)